# Bound on the distance between rotation matrices in 2 dimensions.

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, complex-numbers, rotations

A 2 by 2 rotation matrix is a unitary matrix $$R(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{pmatrix}$$ whose eigenvalues are $\{e^{i\theta},e^{-i\theta}\}$.

Given two rotation matrices $R(\theta)$ and $R(\varphi)$ where $0\leq \theta,\varphi<2\pi$ are angles of rotation about the same axis. I am trying to show that $$\|R(\theta)-R(\varphi)\|\leq |\theta-\varphi|.$$

It's clear that $\|R(\theta)-R(\varphi)\|\leq |e^{i\theta}-e^{i\varphi}|$ since both matrices are diagonal in the same basis.

So I guess I'm wondering why$$|e^{i\theta}-e^{i\varphi}|\leq |\theta-\varphi|\,.$$

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: What exactly is the definition of $\|A - B\|$ in this context? Is $\|\cdot\|$ the spectral norm? The Frobenius norm?

Comment: Yes is the spectral norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
|e^{i \theta} - e^{i\varphi}| = |e^{i \varphi}(e^{i (\theta -\varphi)} - 1)| =  |e^{i (\theta -\varphi)} - 1|,
$$
and apply Euler's formula.

Alternatively, a nice approach is to think geometrically: the distance between two points on the unit circle is less than the arclength along the part of the circumference between them.

via Euler's formula:

$$
|e^{\theta} - 1|^2 = (\cos \theta - 1)^2 + \sin^2 \theta 
\\ = 2 (1 - \cos(\theta)) = 2 (1 - \cos(2[\theta/2]))
\\ = 2(1 - (1 - 2\sin^2 (\theta/2)))\\
= 4 \sin^2(\theta/2) \leq 4(\theta/2)^2 = \theta^2
$$

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed the right geometric picture! I did obtain the formula you mentioned by factoring out the $e^{i\varphi}$. But I couldn't deduce the bound from Euler's formula, it just turned into a trigonometric mess... do you see an easy way to get it analytically?

Comment: For anyone interested the application of Eulers formula I was missing was the identity $|1-e^{2i\theta}|=2|\sin\theta|$.

Comment: @Connor Sorry I didn't answer your question earlier. I've added my own derivation, in case you're interested.